# this code is not work properly in another android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

// Create the array list of to do items
final ArrayList todoItems = new ArrayList();
// Create the array adapter to bind the array to the listview
final ArrayAdapter aa;
aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
todoItems);
// Bind the array adapter to the listview.
myListView.setAdapter(aa);
}

Comment: No formatting, no explanation, no question. How do you expect us to help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using another android then you have to create proper AVD for that application.

if you create highr version application and you run in the liver version android os then it will not give proper output of application.

the start way to use your application in all the android os version, you have create little change in AndroidMenifest.xml file is :

hear minsdkVersion = 2 means your can work in lowest Android OS and maxSdkVersion = 12 means your application is working in latest Android OS version 2.3.3 and another